# Parsing XML document and saving into arraylist or alternative

Tags: xml, vb.net

I do apologise for posting this as it's probably a stupidly simple process, but after trying a few methods I still can't get my head around the best way to make this work.

I've created a program with hard-coded settings, but I want to make it parse an XML file and data from this as settings later on so that other users can update the program without having to update the entire program (Currently only myself can do that and a user-friendly XML file would work wonders).

So far I'm testing the XML reading and processing in another project to get my head around it before importing any of the code into my main program, but I've looked at XMLReader and System.Xml.XmlDocument and didn't know which would be most effective for what I'm trying to achieve.

The XML I'm using is:

```
<ProgramName
    updated="11/12/13"
    lastuser="james.xxxxxxx"
    >
    <school name="school name" id="1">
        <netbios> NETBIOS </netbios>
        <domainname> SCHOOLNAME.local </domainname>
        <drives>
            <!-- Generic variables -->
            <variable name="server1"> \\server1\ </variable>
            <variable name="server2"> \\server2\ </variable>
            <!-- Work drives -->
            <!-- Note, you can use $server1 or $server2 to use the above variables -->
            <restriction usergroup="office users">
                <drive name="Home Drive"> \\server1\officework$ </drive>
                <drive name="Office Drive"> \\server1\Office Shared </drive>
            </restriction>

            <restriction usergroup="staff users">
                <drive name="Home Drive"> \\server1\staffwork$ </drive>
            </restriction>

            <restriction usergroup="all users">
                <drive name="Staff Shared"> \\server1\staff shared </drive>
                <drive name="Pupil Shared"> \\server1\pupil shared </drive> 
                <drive name="Another drive"> \\server1\another drive </drive>
            </restriction>
        </drives>
    </school>
</ProgramName>
```

I've tried to make the XML look as 'pretty' and logical as I could think so that my colleagues could update it without any further knowledge (They are IT engineers but have no knowledge of programming).

Basically, I would appreciate your advice on the best way of saving this data in my program. Do I run through the XML file and save parts into a multidimentional / multiple Lists, Arraylists, etc.? *Please note that the  to  will be repeated several times for different schools, and therefore the file could get relatively large.*

One thing my program will be doing is mapping drives depending upon what user group the user is part of and name them accordingly (eg. from the 'name' attribute) so it will have to loop through all of the appropriate drives, so it makes sense (to me) to save things into a list/array/collection of some sort then run through it.

I have read that using System.Xml.XmlDocument is more flexible than XMLReader, but I had issues with duplicate entries, poor performance, no end element detection. Perhaps a lot of my issues stem from understanding the process or logic behind it.

I'd also like to expand its uses to do other things, but I've fallen at the first hurdle of reading the XML file. I can post my mish-mash of code if that helps at all, but I thought a fresh perspective might be more useful than adapting code that's nowhere near working at a good level.

Sincere apologies if this is in any way inappropriate for SO or I have made any mistakes in posting this.

Kind regards,
James.

**Edit: Is there a way I can reply in full without answering myself?**

I've attached the code code I used for testing (This is just to visualise how it worked).

```
Public Sub DisplayNodes(_XMLNodes As Xml.XmlNodeList)
    For Each xNode As System.Xml.XmlNode In _XMLNodes
        Select Case xNode.NodeType
            Case XmlNodeType.Element
                Output("Element: " & xNode.Name)

                If xNode.Attributes.Count > 0 Then
                    For Each attribute As System.Xml.XmlAttribute In xNode.Attributes
                        Output("Attribute: " & attribute.Name & " = " & attribute.Value)
                    Next
                End If

        End Select

        If xNode.HasChildNodes Then
            DisplayNodes(xNode.ChildNodes)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then my thoughts were to relay this into something that can be referenced directly which  I guess would be a new object (I'm still getting my head around when is the best time to create a new object for something).

I guess I would use XPath to find the appropriate section (eg. the school that the user has selected) and then I need to think what the best kind of storage would be for the drive maps so I can loop through them.

In the hard-coded version, I used a Collection with the Key being the drive letter and the value being the UNC path and looped through the collection to map them. Not great, I know.

Thanks.

**Edit 2**

I've just found http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301220 and using XPath looks really promising.

I'll find what school the user has selected then from here I will create an object containing all of the relevant elements (netbios, domain name, etc.) and would you suggest using some kind of list/array for the drives?

Feeling positive about this, I'll let you know!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your general question:

Depending on the usage of the data, I think I would create one or more classes corresponding to the data. This would be like serilization/deserilization, but you will probably have to do a custom implementation of such.

What I don't understand is your comment about issues with "no end element detection" using System.Xml.XmlDocument. This would mean that the loaded Xml is not wellformed, which make me think that you are creating the xml by string operations.

You should at least be able to do the following:

```
Dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()    
doc.LoadXml(fullFileNamePath)
```

If you cannot, then you need to make your xml wellformed before going any further.

Poor performance can be caused by many things. How big are your files?
Dupplication: I think you would need to explain (a small concrete example).
Usually you would be able to do something like:

```
doc.SelectNodes("/ProgramName/school/drives/restriction[@usergroup = 'office users']/drive"/>
```

Which would select the two drive elements named "Home Drive" and "Office Drive".
This requires knowledge about xpath.

Another way is to use XElement and LINQ, but I don't have much experience with this.

Comment: I think a lot of my problems lie in actually making sense of how I want to (or should) relay the information from the XML. Basically, a user will select their school, then the program will dial a VPN and subsequently run through a list of drive maps.

Instead of using a recursive Subroutine to keep expanding a node's children to find an element, would doc.SelectNodes be a lot more effective (assuming I know the path)?

The sluggishness was my own fault in how I was trying to code something (will post an example) and the duplication was also a similar issue.

Comment: Using XPath seems to be the way to go. I'll rewrite and try from here.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would always use the intrinsic methods unless they have been proven to be faulty in some way. So XPath, yes :-)
I had a slight error in my doc.SelectNodes, which I have corrected now.